# Apache2 erro ao instalar

Tags: apache

Ao tentar realizar a instalação do apache2 ocorre os seguintes erros, alguem poderia por favor me ajudar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algum erro no arquivo /etc/apach2/apache2.conf, poderia postar ele pra gente olhar? você chegou a modificar ele?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o problema não seja na instalação não...

Pelo que o erro diz, ele já está instalado e na hora do start esta dando um erro no arquivo /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.
 A descrição do erro diz que a tag  não está fechada (Abra o arquivo e de uma olhada. Para fechar a tag `<VirtualHost>`use `</VirtualHost>`

Outra coisa, algo legal de se colocar junto da pergunta é a versão do linux em que vc está usando e qual é a distro especifica e tambem nos mostre o jeito que vc está instalando o apache2.